# How to tell order of value and children in XML using SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

Let's say i have this XML

```
<data>
  <p>
    Hello 
    <em>World!</em>
  </p>
  <p>
    <em>Hello </em>
    World!
  </p>
</data>
```

How can i tell from my PHP script which element comes first, the value of the node

or the children's value ? I use SimpleXMLElement but could not find any index-number or something to process them in the right order.

To demonstrate the problem i made script PHP script:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<data>
    <p>
        Hello
        <em>World!</em>
    </p>
    <p>
        <em>Hello </em>
        World!
    </p>
</data>
XML;

$sx = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach($sx->children() as $p)
{
    print("Value first = " . trim((string)$p) . ' ' . trim($p->children()[0]) . "\n");
    print("Child first = " . trim($p->children()[0]) . ' ' . trim((string)$p) . "\n");
}
```

This will output:

```
Value first = Hello World!
Child first = World! Hello
Value first = World! Hello
Child first = Hello World!
```

It shows that depending on what the programmer assumes comes first (the p-nodes value or the value of the p-nodes child) the output is mixed.

What i try to find out is, how to tell from my script if the p-nodes value comes before the child(ren) or after?

Comment: Your two `<p>` elements are identical; so what exactly is your expected output?

Comment: What’s wrong with just using `children`?

Comment: I've added an example PHP above to make the problem more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The following is somewhat hacky, but - if I you understand correctly - it will get you at least close to what you're looking for. Specifically, assuming that your xml structure is **exactly** as in your question (including the line breaks), this will tell you which `<p>` elements have an `<em>` child which is the first child element inside `<p>`, (as opposed to an `<em>`which follows a text element).

Since you are dealing with xml, I used xpath. To demonstrate the output, I modified the xml a little:

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' standalone='yes'?>
<data>
    <p loc="1">
        Hello
        <em>World!</em>
    </p>
    <p loc="2">
        <em>Hello </em>
        World!
    </p>
    <p loc="3">
        Hello
        <em>World!</em>
    </p>
    <p>
        <em loc="4">Hello </em>
        World!
    </p>
</data>
XML;

$sx = simplexml_load_string($string);

$results = $sx->xpath('//text()[normalize-space()][(count(preceding-sibling::em)+1)=2]/..//@loc');

foreach($results as $result) {     
   echo $result;
   echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
2
4
```